# CMake Error at android.toolchain.cmake:621 (message):

Tags: android-ndk, cmake

I am getting the error with android ndk even though i have set ndk to my path.

```
CMake Error at android.toolchain.cmake:621 (message):
Could not find any working toolchain in the NDK.  Probably your Android  NDK  is broken.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.5.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:98 (include)
CMakeLists.txt:52 (project)


CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```